# Trigger that will deny change for users other then SYSTEM

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

trying to deny access for all users except SYSTEM using trigger. And I'm TOTALLY new on Oracle, sorry. This generates an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') FROM DUAL) != 'SYSTEM' THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,'not allowed!');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Could you copy/paste the error do you get ?

Comment: "
ERROR at line 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null others 
     avg
   count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance
   execute forall merge time timestamp interval date
   
     pipe
   
   

1. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t1
2.   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON table1
3. FOR EACH ROW
4. BEGIN
"

Comment: within pl/sql always an `into` clause has to be provided; so implement a `declare l_temp varchar2 (1000)` and then re-arrange the select to a `select sys_contect(...) into l_temp etc etc`

Comment: That was correct, thanx!

Comment: Simply write ´if user <> 'SYSTEM" then´

Comment: I'd say the only problem with this approach is that the owner of the table can always just disable the trigger. You're better off making sure that no-one can connect as the owner of the object, and then don't grant I/U/D to anyone except SYSTEM.